# a footer position:fixed to viewport bottom, but with a height limit

Tags: html, css

In this sample, we have a (very fat) footer that is fixed to the bottom of the page. When viewing with a short viewport, it overlays the header and body. Is there any way to keep the footer outside certain minimum distance from the top, with css only?

Have tried min-height and height on `body` and `#outW`, but nothing has any effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/2XsNH/1/

(move the bottom of the browser window way up to see the yellow footer lay over the header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry if my description of the problem fell short, but this is what I was looking for -

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

the problem was that my first instinct, `position:fixed`, won't ever work, because an element with fixed positioning is completely broken out of the document flow. So the above page uses a negative margin trick on the content area to make room for the header.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this in pure CSS is to give the main contents a `position: relative` and a `z-index` of, say, `10`, and  the footer one of `9`.

Comment: hmm, so with the intention of getting the footer to go _under_ the header? I am looking to have the footer "stop" if the viewport is smaller than X pixels high, so it doesn't collide at all.

Comment: @sbeam I can't think of a way to achieve that in pure CSS. I'm not saying it's impossible - maybe with some creative use of a relative `max-height`... But I can't think of any

Comment: @sbeam: If "stopped" then where should the footer go? It has a height of 240px and you want it to stay 100px from the bottom and 100px from the top. If the viewport is less than 440px high, then what should the browser do according to you? It cannot concur with all settings and has to break either one of them, otherwise the numbers do not add up. if you want it to break the bottom:100px then it's just a regular flow of divs with a h-scrollbar.